# How to automate cp with user input on linux

Tags: ubuntu, automation, cp

I want to automate CP to make it easier as I tend to use linux to do alot of data recovery and permission stripping. I know something similar can be done on windows where you enter the path for input and output then it just dumps with already selected variables. If yous could help i would be really thankful

Comment: I'm guessing you're not referring to `cp`, the file copying command. Please update your question to clarify what you mean by "CP".

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to achieve, you could probably define an alias in ~/.bash_aliases which will help you, if you often type the same code.